# how to fix the 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'profile' error?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I'm writing a chat app for a hypothetical social network but when I try to open the chat page I give the following error 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'profile' error .
I think there may be problem in the models file but I can't really figure out how to fix it and I'm really confused now!? can anyone give any suggestions??

parts of the chat views.py

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    print request.POST
    request.user.profile.is_chat_user=True
logged_users = []

if request.user.username and request.user.profile.is_chat_user:
    context = {'logged_users':logged_users}
    cu = request.user.profile
    cu.is_chat_user = True
    cu.last_accessed = utcnow()
    cu.save()

    return render(request, 'djangoChat/index.html', context)

    try:
            eml = request.COOKIES[ 'email' ]
            pwd = request.COOKIES[ 'password' ]
    except KeyError:
            d = {'server_message':"You are not logged in."}
            query_str = urlencode(d)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/?'+query_str)

    try:
                    client = Vertex.objects.get(email = eml)
                    context = {'logged_users':logged_users}
                    cu = request.user.profile
                    cu.is_chat_user = True
                    cu.last_accessed = utcnow()
                    cu.save()
                    if client.password != pwd:
                            raise LookupError()
    except Vertex.DoesNotExist:
                    sleep(3)
                    d = {'server_message':"Wrong username or password."}
                    query_str = urlencode(d)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/?'+query_str)

    return render_to_response('djangoChat/index.html',
{"USER_EMAIL":eml,request.user.profile.is_chat_user:True},
context_instance=RequestContext(request))



 @csrf_exempt
def chat_api(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    d = json.loads(request.body)
    msg =  d.get('msg')
    user = request.user.username 
    gravatar = request.user.profile.gravatar_url
    m = Message(user=user,message=msg,gravatar=gravatar)
    m.save()


    res = {'id':m.id,'msg':m.message,'user':m.user,'time':m.time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p').lstrip('0'),'gravatar':m.gravatar}
    data = json.dumps(res)
    return HttpResponse(data,content_type="application/json")


# get request
r = Message.objects.order_by('-time')[:70]
res = []
for msgs in reversed(r) :
    res.append({'id':msgs.id,'user':msgs.user,'msg':msgs.message,'time':msgs.time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p').lstrip('0'),'gravatar':msgs.gravatar})

data = json.dumps(res)


return HttpResponse(data,content_type="application/json")

def logged_chat_users(request):

u = Vertex.objects.filter(is_chat_user=True)

for j in u:
    elapsed = utcnow() - j.last_accessed
    if elapsed > datetime.timedelta(seconds=35):

        j.is_chat_user = False
        j.save()

uu = Vertex.objects.filter(is_chat_user=True)


d = []
for i in uu:
    d.append({'username': i.username,'gravatar':i.gravatar_url,'id':i.userID})
data = json.dumps(d)


return HttpResponse(data,content_type="application/json")
```

and parts of my chat models:

```
class Message(models.Model):
user = models.CharField(max_length=200)

message = models.TextField(max_length=200)
time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
gravatar = models.CharField(max_length=300)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user
def save(self):
    if self.time == None:
        self.time = datetime.now()
    super(Message, self).save()




def generate_avatar(email):
           a = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/"
           a+=hashlib.md5(email.lower()).hexdigest()
           a+='?d=identicon'
           return a
def hash_username(username):
           a = binascii.crc32(username)
           return a
 # the problem seems to be here ??!
 User.profile = property(lambda u: Vertex.objects.get_or_create(user=u,defaults={'gravatar_url':generate_avatar(u.email),'username':u.username,'userID':hash_username(u.username)})[0])
```

and finally parts of the another app(ChatUsers):

```
class Vertex(models.Model,object):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
#user_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)

username = models.CharField(max_length=300)
userID =models.IntegerField()

Message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
is_chat_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
gravatar_url = models.CharField(max_length=300,null=True, blank=True)
last_accessed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 10):

Because that user has not logged in yet. Django treat them as AnonymousUser and AnonymousUser does not have the `profile` property.

If the view is only for logged in user, you can add the `login_required` decorator to the view function to force the login process. Otherwise, you need to judge whether a user is anonymous with the `is_authenticated` function.

Reference: [Using the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users)

Comment: Your recommedation is effective in case of that view require access by user authenticated onlying, but How to can I make that one view, let access to anonymous users, and the same time, ask in her the profile property?

Comment: Use the 'if user is not None:' as outlined in the docs above for views.  Use {% if request.user %} in the templates.